# File not found while deploying Cordova App with Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with the latest updates.
I'm writing a mobile app with Apache Cordova. Until this morning everything was fine, but now I can't deploy to my Android Device. Yesterday everything was OK.
All I got is twice the Message

> Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

What means in english, "The system can't find the stated file".

[image]

I've already set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to "Diagnostic", but there are no more informations.

How can I find out, what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "ADT_HOME" (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) to the system environment variables! This solved the same issue for me!

Hope this helps.